# How to check if user input includes all of needed information in random order?

Tags: javascript

I have a task and I need a function that validate '123456' equals '213456','312456' etc. Maybe, I missing something, but absolutely have no idea how to validate it

I tried to do regexp like `if(userInput = [/answer/g] return true`  but it isn't work

Comment: do I understand correctly you want to check if the number entered by the user contains specific digits in any order. for example 123 == 321 ?

Comment: absolutely right

Comment: only numbers 123==321 or letters too abc == cba ?

Comment: I need this validation for string that includes only numbers :)

Answer (score 0):

The following checks that one string is a [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of another as long as all the characters in the set string are different.

```js
let s = new Set('123456');
let input = '213456';
if(input.length === s.size && [...input].every(c => s.has(c)))
    return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let string = '123457';
let user_input ='623451';

function compare(string, user_input)
{
if(string.length == user_input.length)
{
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (user_input.includes(string[i])) continue;
    else
    return false;
  }  
  return true;
}
else
{
console.log('failure');
}
}
console.log(compare(string, user_input));
```

you might like this solution

Comment: Your code helped so much! TY

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution which runs in `O(n)` and can also be used if the expected string contains duplicate charaters like e.g. `112233` (see second example within the code), which other solutions posted here are not taking into consideration.

The idea here is that you first create a lookup table (I am using a JavaScript object here) once which holds all the numbers/ characters and their count within the expected word. Then using this lookup table I check for any of the characters in a user supplied word (the word which has to be validated) if it has all the expected characters and (this is the distinction to other answers posted here) if their count matches the expected count of said character/ number. If one string is a [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of the other the lookup table should have `0` as the count for every single character. If any character is not `0`, it is not a permutation.

```js
function validate(userInput, validOptionsMap) {
  // create a copy as we are mutating the values within the object
  const validOptionsWithCount = { ...validOptionsMap
  };
  const elementsMatch = userInput.split("").every(input => {
    if (validOptionsWithCount[input]) {
      const count = validOptionsWithCount[input];
      if (count === 0) {
        return false;
      }
      validOptionsWithCount[input] = count - 1;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });
  if (!elementsMatch) return false;
  return Object.values(validOptionsWithCount).every(count => count === 0);
};


function buildLookupTableForExpectedPermutation(expectedPalindrome) {
  return expectedPalindrome.split("")
    .reduce((all, cur) => (all[cur] ?
      all[cur] = all[cur] + 1 :
      all[cur] = 1, all), {});
}

// Your example
const permutation = "123456";
const validOptionsWithCount = buildLookupTableForExpectedPermutation(permutation);
console.log(`Checking for permutations of ${permutation}`)
console.log("123456:", validate("123456", validOptionsWithCount)); // true
console.log("123457:", validate("123457", validOptionsWithCount)); // false
console.log("265413:", validate("265413", validOptionsWithCount)); // true
console.log("2654131:", validate("2654131", validOptionsWithCount)); // false
console.log("261413:", validate("261413", validOptionsWithCount)); // false

// example with multiple identical values (other solutions posted here will fail at least one of these tests)
const permutation2 = "112233";
const validOptionsWithCount2 = buildLookupTableForExpectedPermutation(permutation2);
console.log(`Checking for permutations of ${permutation2}`)
console.log("112233:", validate("112233", validOptionsWithCount2)); // true
console.log("123123:", validate("123123", validOptionsWithCount2)); // true
console.log("123131:", validate("123131", validOptionsWithCount2)); // false
console.log("1231231:", validate("1231231", validOptionsWithCount2)); // false
console.log("12312:", validate("12312", validOptionsWithCount2)); // false
```